# how to access table across multiple data server

Tags: sql, sybase

I have two Sysbase servers , server1 and server2 . I have a stored procedure declared and running on server1. In that SP i want to access table from server2. How can i do that? Also my both instances are running in a UNIX box

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, read more about "**Proxy tables**" at [Sybase Infocenter](http://infocenter.sybase.com) (search for: create proxy_table statement) Afaik, there has to be remote server declared as well. I think it's documented well.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a 'Remote Server' in the database that has the stored procedure.
You will need to tell it what the 'Server Type' is and how to connect (ODBC, for instance), then in the connection information, you can simply put the DSN name.

Now, you can create proxy tables to reference tables in your other server.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the four part name. See here: http://www.dbforums.com/sybase/1001475-call-sql-server-stored-proc-sybase.html

Comment: -1; Author said they are both Sybase servers, neither being SQL Server.